# Error Must declare scalar variable in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server, visual-studio-code

I'm currently experiencing with JSON and SQL, I'm trying to write a dynamic sql command but sql server always says "*Must declare the scalar variable "@AgencesP"*" and I don't know what i'm doing wrong because if I try a `SELECT * FROM @AgencesP` i have my data.

```
DECLARE @AgencesP TABLE (Agence INT, Groupe INT)
DECLARE @P VARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @SQLC VARCHAR(MAX)

SET @P = N'{ "Agences":[ 1, 6 ],"Groupes":[ 40, 45 ] }' --Agences

INSERT INTO @AgencesP (Agence, Groupe)
SELECT *
    FROM OpenJSON(@P,'$.Agences') 
        WITH(Agence INT '$')
    LEFT JOIN OpenJSON(@P,'$.Groupes')
        WITH(Groupe INT '$') ON 1=1    

SET @SQLC = 'SELECT TOP 20 * '+
    'FROM GRH_T_Salarie '+
    'INNER JOIN @AgencesP ON GRH_T_Salarie.IdAgenceExploitation ='+@AgencesP.Agence
```

Comment: Your dynamic sql executes in a different context and cannot access the local variables in your script. But there is no reason to use dynamic sql at all - which eliminates the problem. It is not clear why you need to use JSON either to provide a set of static rows. Looks like you vastly over-complicate the code.

Comment: I'm trying with json because i will need to use it after in a more complex procedure so I'm trying with a simplified structure ^^ .

Answer (score 1):

You can simplify the statement:

```
DECLARE @P VARCHAR(MAX)
SET @P = N'{ "Agences":[ 1, 6 ],"Groupes":[ 40, 45 ] }' --Agences

SELECT TOP 20 *
FROM GRH_T_Salarie 
INNER JOIN (
   SELECT Agence, Groupe
   FROM OPENJSON(@P,'$.Agences') WITH (Agence INT '$')
   OUTER APPLY OPENJSON(@P,'$.Groupes') WITH (Groupe INT '$')
) agnt ON GRH_T_Salarie.IdAgenceExploitation = agnt.Agence
```

Of course, if you are *... trying to write a dynamic sql command ...* (although you do not need a dynamic statement), passing a table as a parameter needs a table type declaration:

```
CREATE TYPE AgencesPType AS TABLE (Agence INT, Groupe INT)
DECLARE @AgencesP AgencesPType
DECLARE @P VARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @SQLC NVARCHAR(MAX)

SET @P = N'{ "Agences":[ 1, 6 ],"Groupes":[ 40, 45 ] }' --Agences

INSERT INTO @AgencesP (Agence, Groupe)
SELECT *
    FROM OpenJSON(@P,'$.Agences') 
        WITH(Agence INT '$')
    LEFT JOIN OpenJSON(@P,'$.Groupes')
        WITH(Groupe INT '$') ON 1=1    

SET @SQLC = 
   N'SELECT TOP 20 * '+
   N'FROM GRH_T_Salarie g '+
   N'INNER JOIN @AgencesP a ON g.IdAgenceExploitation = a.Agence'

EXEC sp_executesql @SQLC, N'@AgencesP AgencesPType READONLY', @AgencesP
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with an alias, like:

```
  SET @SQLC = 'SELECT TOP 20 * '+
    'FROM GRH_T_Salarie '+
    'INNER JOIN @AgencesP agnt ON GRH_T_Salarie.IdAgenceExploitation =agnt.Agence'
```

Comment: Thanks, but unfortunately when i try to execute it, it says "the table variable @AgencesP" must be declared.

Answer (score 0):

Edit : I got it working by removing the dynamic SQL command :)
Code if someone need it :

```
DECLARE @AgencesP TABLE (Agence INT, Groupe INT)
DECLARE @P VARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @SQLC VARCHAR(255)

SET @P = N'{ "Agences":[ 1, 6 ],"Groupes":[ 40, 45 ] }' --Agences

INSERT INTO @AgencesP (Agence, Groupe)
SELECT *
    FROM OpenJSON(@P,'$.Agences') 
        WITH(Agence INT '$')
    INNER JOIN OpenJSON(@P,'$.Groupes')
        WITH(Groupe INT '$') ON 1=1    

SELECT TOP 20 *
    FROM GRH_T_Salarie 
    INNER JOIN @AgencesP agnt ON GRH_T_Salarie.IdAgenceExploitation = agnt.Agence
```